Is X-23 in Deadpool & Wolverine the same character Dafne Keen played in Logan?
The trailer for Deadpool & Wolverine (2024) features Dafne Keen reprising her role as Laura/X-23, which she originally played in Logan (2017). Folks who've watched Deadpool & Wolverine know that the Wolverine in the film

 isn't the same variant we saw in Logan, but

what about Laura? Is she a variant, or is this the same character we met in Logan?
Given that Deadpool & Wolverine explores the multiverse concept, I'm wondering how X-23's character fits into this narrative. Are we seeing an older version of the same Laura, or is this an entirely different variant from another timeline?

When dealing with a multiverse with potentially infinite variations and duplicate forks in time it's really not possible to say she's the exact same character.  Rather she appears to have the same past as the character in Logan.

X-23 in Deadpool & Wolverine is the same character from Logan
Dafne Keen has confirmed that her portrayal of Laura/X-23 in Deadpool & Wolverine is a direct continuation of her character from Logan. In an interview with Phase Zero, Keen shed light on X-23's journey since the events of Logan.



After Logan's conclusion, Laura went along with the other Transigen children for a few years before being zapped (or "pruned," to borrow Loki terminology) to the Void. According to Keen, her character has been trapped there for a few years, setting the stage for her appearance in Deadpool & Wolverine.

Wait. So Deadpool and Wolverine is set after Logan? The grim future where Prof X is senile?

@Jontia Yes. Deadpool even digs up the grave of the variant of Wolverine in Logan.
